# Lucene Query - AND operator failing in Azure Search?

Tags: lucene, azure-cognitive-search

I have a search index of sandwiches. The index has three fields: id, meat, and bread. Each field is an Edm.String. In this index, here is a subset of my data:

```
ID | Meat       | Bread
-----------------------
1  | Ham        | White
2  | Turkey     | Hoagie
3  | Tuna       | Wheat
4  | Roast Beef | White
5  | Ham        | Wheat
6  | Roast Beef | Rye
7  | Turkey     | Wheat
```

I need to write a query that returns all ham or turkey sandwiches on wheat bread. In an attempt to do this, I've created the following:

```
{
  "search":"(meat:(Ham|Turkey) AND bread:\"Wheat\")",
  "searchMode":"all",
  "select":"id,meat,bread"
}
```

When I run this query, I'm not seeing any results. What am I missing? What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to understand full queries. Do field-level queries support the phrase operator? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use "queryType": "full" to request the Lucene syntax. See an [example on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt589323.aspx#bkmk_example).

That said, what you're trying to accomplish is easier and more efficiently done using **filters**. Assuming you make the relevant fields in your index filterable, you can use the following filter expression for your example: $filter=(meat eq 'Ham' or meat eq 'Turkey') and bread eq 'Wheat'. For more on filters, see [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn798921.aspx). Hope this helps!